# While loop iterates when it should not

Tags: php

I;m working in WordPress here. I have the following function, it is called from outside the function and then calls itself recursively through a while loop.

```
    public function parent_category_has_fiance($cat_id) {
        global $wpdb;
        $terms = $wpdb->get_row("
                            SELECT
                                term_id, 
                                parent 
                            FROM
                                $wpdb->term_taxonomy
                            WHERE 
                                term_id = $cat_id
                                ");

        $terms = int($terms->parent);
        //var_dump($terms);

        while ($terms > 0) {
            //do some logic
            $parent_id = $terms->parent;
            $this->parent_category_has_fiance($parent_id);
        }
    }
```

However the while loop is iterating endlessly while `$terms` is equal to 0. Could anyone suggest anything which is obviously wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the endless loop is dead simple.

You are *never* updating the value of `$terms` inside the loop body, which is being used in loop condition.

So the loop body is executed either zero times or infinitely.

---

The fix seems to replace the `while` with the `if`, because you handle the parent via a recursive call already. However, I may be wrong since your function doesn't return anything and seems to have no side effects...

Answer (score 1):

The misunderstanding lies in the scope of the `$terms` variable. This variable has scope that is local to the function call it exists in. The loop

```
while ($terms > 0) {
    //do some logic
    $parent_id = $terms->parent;
    $this->parent_category_has_fiance($parent_id);
}
```

is referencing the `$terms` variable, but when `parent_category_has_fiance` is called, the `$terms` variable inside that function only exists there. That is, it doesn't change `$terms` that the while loop is looking at.